# Windows short file name

Tags: window

How do I manually create short file names in Windows if by default short file name is not assigned?

When we run command as below `c:\dir x` we can see the list of short file name.

But I want to create new short file name if not exist in list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about Windows not generating SFNs in general, then that question belongs on SuperUser instead of here. For the record, you can turn the [registry entry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210638?wa=wsignin1.0) back on as so:

```
fsutil disable8dot3 set 0
```

If you are asking about selecting specific SFNs instead of letting Windows automatically generate them, you can do that too:

```
fsutil file setshortname *LFN* *SFN*
```

Alternately, you can do it programmatically with the [`SetFileShortName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365543.aspx) command.

These only work with NTFS volumes. On FAT volumes, there is no practical way to specify the SFN. You would need to directly edit the directory entry, making sure to [update the LFN checksums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#VFAT_long_file_names).